# How to count the number of authors in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How to count the number of authors in a column? I need the count on

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: See this post for [getting the distinct values in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have 10 authors in a column A.
The first record in A2 and last in A11. Then You can get the count in A12 by using this formula

`=COUNTA(A2:A11)`

Comment: You could also use `=11-2+1`.  But I don't think that is what the person is asking.